# Create UITableView in Storyboard in ContainerView with Delegate

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a container view in a View Controller in Storyboard. In this container I want 5 tableView controllers like so:

[image: Container View with 5 tableViews flush against each other each 1/5 the width of container]

I want each tableView controlled by one instance of a controller I call `ContainerTableViewController`. I create 5 instances of this VC and have each one instance control one of the tableViews above.

Here's where I get stuck. I can connect each of these tableViews to `ContainerTableViewController` but then I have 5 tableView instances connected to one controller. What I want again is one of these VC instances to control 1 tableView. I do not want to create a tableView programmatically since I want to lay these tableViews out in Storyboard. Is there any way to do this or does each tableview needs it's own separate View Controller class?

Comment: You should use `UICollectionView` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can make 5 containerViews and link all of them to ContainerTableViewController on storyboard. Then you can get 5 instances of ContainerTableViewController with different tableView